# Why is this code displaying an infinite loop of 1 instead of Armstrong numbers between 100 and 500?

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

This code displays an infinite loop of 1, but I don't want it to! What's wrong in the code below?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
     int i,num1=0,num2=0,num3=0;   // declares four variables
     for(i=100;i<=500;i++){       // for loop initiated from 100
           int j=i;               // since value of i gets changed afterwards hence store its current value in a variable
           num1=i%10;
           i=i/10;
           num2=i%10;
           num3=j/100;

          if(num1*num1*num1 + num2*num2*num2 + num3*num3*num3 == j)
                 cout<<j<<endl;           
                // displays the number for above condition matched
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Print the value of i inside the loop to see what's going on.

Comment: IOCCC winner of 2016

Comment: @molbdnilo num3 has value of 1 , it is only displaying that ,but i have copied the value of i into j in beginning of for loop

Comment: There's a very helpful tool on your computer called a "debugger". Using this useful tool you can step through your code, one line at a time, see the values of all the variables, and figure out why is it doing what it is doing.

Comment: @SimritSingh I wasn't asking what num3 is. Print i - it is not what you think it is. (Messing with the loop variable is messy.)

Answer (score 5):

You divide "i" every time in loop, so it'll never become more than 500.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `i = i / 10`, because it makes the loop infinite...

> `i = 100` then `i = 10` at the end
>
> `i++`; `i = 11`
>
> `i = 11` then `i = 1.1` at the end
>
> `i++`; `i = 2.1`
>
> `i = 2.1` then `i = 0.21` at the end
>
> `i++`; `i = 1.21`
>
> `i = 1.21` then `i = 0.121` at the end
>
> *And so on......*